# Elasticsearch data migration

Tags: migration, elasticsearch

I have installed the version 0.90.10 of Elasticsearch. I have large amounts of indexed information.

How I can migrate the information to Elasticsearch 1.0.1?

Answer (score 9):

You can simply move/use your data folder by the new elasticsearch version. This works for upgrading elasticsearch. Moving a data folder into an older elasticsearch version will not work.

Like this it is not necessary to reindex your data.